# Confusion: When can I preform operation of infinity in limit (without using the explanation of Epsilon Delta Definition)

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Question 1:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$$
Knowing this:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}$$
The denominator of question 1 is $\infty$, therefore, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}} = 0$

My confusion: Why could we assume that $\sqrt{\infty+1}+\sqrt{\infty} = \infty$ since there aren't any algebraic operation on inf and negative inf? e.g. This operation is wrong $\lim_{x\to\infty}x-x = \infty - \infty$

Question 2:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{3+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
Knowing that $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{3+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}$ is continuous.

Using this theorem
[image]

$$\frac{1+2^{\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{x}}}{3+2^{\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$\frac{1+2^{-\infty}}{3+2^{-\infty}}$$
since $2^{-\infty} = \frac{1}{2^{\infty}}$, Therefore
$$\frac{1+2^{-\infty}}{3+2^{-\infty}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

My confusion: Why could we assume that $2^{-\infty} = \frac{1}{2^{\infty}}$?

Comment: That is two questions. In neither case can you properly substitute $\infty$ into equalities, but instead (for example in the first) say $\sqrt{x+1}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ increase without an upper bound, so their sum does too, and the reciprocal of their sum therefore is positive but can be made arbitrarily small.  Better to do this with an $\epsilon$ argument

Comment: $x\to\infty$ is not just directly plugging $x=\infty$. Maybe studying the epsilon-delta definition of the limit will help.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, just a symbol. For example, the notation $2^{-\infty}$ is not correct. If you have a function $f$ that **tends** to $\infty$ at some point from left or right, then $2^{-f}$ **tends** to $0$ in the same conditions. Writing $2^{-\infty}=0$ is not correct, just a mnemothecnic rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually substitute $-\frac{1}{M}$ for $x$, in case $x\rightarrow 0^{-}$ and $\frac{1}{M}$ in case $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ and then let $M\rightarrow\infty$. For example,

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{1+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{3+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+2^{-M}}{3+2^{-M}}=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{M}+1}{3.2^{M}+1}=\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\frac{y+1}{3y+1}.
$$
It reduced to a rational function limit problem.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

Note that in your case both $\sqrt{1+x}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ have the same sign, i.e., you do not get anything of the type $\infty-\infty$.

Question 2:

Note that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $-\delta<x<0$ then $2^{\frac{1}{x}}<\epsilon=2^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I got what you meant in the first one but my math course didn't cover the Epsilon Delta Definition of a Limit. I only learned the informal way of the definition, when x tends to c if the value of f(x) gets close to L.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confused about this, then don't write equations with $\infty$ in there.  Instead write in terms of limits:

As $x \to \infty$ we have:
$$
\sqrt{x} \to \infty\\
\sqrt{x+1} \to \infty\\
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1} \to \infty\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}} \to 0 .
$$

And: as $x \to 0^-$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{x} \to -\infty\\
2^{1/x} \to 0\\
1+2^{1/x} \to 1\\
3+2^{1/x} \to 3\\
\frac{1+2^{1/x}}{3+2^{1/x}} \to \frac{1}{3}
$$

If you write it out in steps like this, then maybe you will find out which of the steps you do not understand.

Only after you have lots of experience doing it this multi-step way should you start writing equations with $\infty$ in there; but always keep in mind that what it really means is the multi-step calculations.  With that "lots of experience" you can do it in your head.

Comment: Congratulations for the $100k$ ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

For question 2:
Let $g(x) = 2^{\frac{1}{x}} and f(x) = \frac{1+x}{3+x}$
Using the theorem[image]

$$lim_{x\to0^-}f(g(x))$$
$$=lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{3+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$=\frac{1+lim_{x\to0^-}2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{3+lim_{x\to0^-}2^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$=\frac{1+lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{2^{-\frac{1}{x}}}}{3+lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{2^{-\frac{1}{x}}}}$$
Since $lim_{x\to\infty}2^{x} = \infty$
$$\frac{1+0}{3+0}=\frac{1}{3}$$